# OSX cocoa app - Get safari tab info

Tags: macos, cocoa, safari

I'm wondering if it's possible to get any tab/window info from safari programmatically?

Is there a library to do it?

I'd prefer not applescript, as I've found that - I'd like to know if, and how it's possible in the Cocoa framework.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The goal is to understand browsing habits of a user while this program is turned on, they will have accessibility enabled for the program.

Comment: @Jono Did you find any answer to this. I am also stuck and figuring this out.

Comment: @vicky at the time there was no way except through apple script

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Reference/ScriptingBridgeFramework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005074), which is like AppleScript translated into Objective-C, or with [accessibility objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/), which you can inspect with Developer Tool Accessibility Inspector. Both technogies have their quirks and aren't documented very well.

**Edit:**

Scripting Bridge example:

```
SafariApplication *SafariApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
for (SafariWindow *window in SafariApp.windows)
{
    for (SafariTab *tab in window.tabs)
        NSLog(@"%@", tab.name);
}
```

The hierarchy of accessibility objects in Safari is

```
AXApplication
 AXWindow
  AXTabGroup
   AXRadioButton
```

Example (doesn't win a prize in a beauty contest):

```
static NSArray *getAXUIElements(AXUIElementRef theContainer, CFStringRef theRole)
{
    // get children of theContainer
    AXError error;
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    CFTypeRef children;
    error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(theContainer, kAXChildrenAttribute, &children);
    if (error != kAXErrorSuccess)
        return nil;
    // filter children whose role is theRole
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(children); i++)
    {
        AXUIElementRef child = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(children, i);
        CFTypeRef role;
        error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(child, kAXRoleAttribute, &role);
        if (error == kAXErrorSuccess)
        {
            if (CFStringCompare(role, theRole, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
                [array addObject:(__bridge id)child];
            CFRelease(role);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(children);
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

static void logTabs()
{
    // get the title of every tab of every window of Safari
    NSArray *appArray = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
    AXUIElementRef SafariApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication([[appArray objectAtIndex:0] processIdentifier]);
    if (SafariApp)
    {
        NSArray *windowArray = getAXUIElements(SafariApp, kAXWindowRole);
        for (id window in windowArray)
        {
            NSArray *tabGroupArray = getAXUIElements((__bridge AXUIElementRef)(window), kAXTabGroupRole);
            for (id tabGroup in tabGroupArray)
            {
                NSArray *radioButtonArray = getAXUIElements((__bridge AXUIElementRef)(tabGroup), kAXRadioButtonRole);
                for (id radioButton in radioButtonArray)
                {
                    CFTypeRef title = NULL;
                    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((__bridge AXUIElementRef)radioButton, kAXTitleAttribute, &title);
                    if (error == kAXErrorSuccess)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"%@", title);
                        CFRelease(title);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        CFRelease(SafariApp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate this task with a bit of functional code please? The task is just getting a (or all) tabs of safari.

Comment: Although this answer could allow to retrieve current open tabs, it's not event driven, and will eventually fail.