# Get the Title or the Number of the Tabs opened in Safari or Google chrome programatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, process

Here I am trying to know about the processes or the applications that are running on my Mac. I have developed a cocoa application in which I can get the information about Applications that are currently running on my mac using the code below.

`NSArray *runningApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];`

However, now I want to get number or the title of the Tabs opened in any browser installed on my mac. Please tell me the way how can I achieve that, if you have any idea about that.

Below is the code I came across on stackoverflow and the link I mentioned in one of my comments.

And I am calling logTabs(). However it is not returning me the title of the tabs.

```
static NSArray *getAXUIElements(AXUIElementRef theContainer, CFStringRef theRole)
{
    // get children of theContainer
    AXError error;
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    CFTypeRef children;
    error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(theContainer, kAXChildrenAttribute, &children);
    if (error != kAXErrorSuccess)
        return nil;
    // filter children whose role is theRole
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(children); i++)
    {
        AXUIElementRef child = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(children, i);
        CFTypeRef role;
        error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(child, kAXRoleAttribute, &role);
        if (error == kAXErrorSuccess)
        {
            if (CFStringCompare(role, theRole, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
                [array addObject:(__bridge id)child];
            CFRelease(role);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(children);
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

static void logTabs()
{
    // get the title of every tab of every window of Safari

 NSArray *appArray = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.google.Chrome"];
 AXUIElementRef SafariApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication([[appArray objectAtIndex:0] processIdentifier]);
    if (SafariApp)
    {
        NSLog(@"titile --- 0000 is %lu", (unsigned long)appArray.count);

        NSArray *windowArray = getAXUIElements(SafariApp, kAXWindowRole);
        for (id window in windowArray)
        {

            NSArray *tabGroupArray = getAXUIElements((__bridge AXUIElementRef)(window), kAXTabGroupRole);
            for (id tabGroup in tabGroupArray)
            {

                NSArray *radioButtonArray = getAXUIElements((__bridge AXUIElementRef)(tabGroup), kAXRadioButtonRole);
                for (id radioButton in radioButtonArray)
                {
                    CFTypeRef title = NULL;
                    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue((__bridge AXUIElementRef)radioButton, kAXTitleAttribute, &title);
                    if (error == kAXErrorSuccess)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Title of the tab is %@", title);
                        CFRelease(title);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        CFRelease(SafariApp);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to do any good for your purpose.  Your best chance is to use AppleScript.  See the dictionaries for either web browser.

Comment: @ElTomato I have came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440157/osx-cocoa-app-get-safari-tab-info and tried to use it. However I am still not able to get it working for me. Can you please help me with this if you have any indepth idea about it.

Comment: "I am still not able to get it working for me"  What doesn't work?  You aren't showing a single line of code for using AppleScript.  Besies, I haven't used AppleScript in my applications for several years.  So I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @ElTomato I have updated the Question with code I am using.